# Atom doesn't recognize the code language most of the time

Tags: atom-editor

I've recently started to use the Atom editor again because it offers some good features.
However it doesn't recognize the code in my files most of the time.

I use it mainly to look through SSIS files - meaning they are in XML-format but have other file endings like ".conmgr" or ".dtsx". Yet they all start with `<?xml version="1.0"?>`.

Now to my question:
Can I somehow set the standard language from "Auto Detect" to "XML" or is there any package so that Atom starts to recognize those files as XML-code?

Since this is my first time using stackoverflow to ask something I hope I've done everything right.

Thank you in advance!

The two picures show two different files. Both ending on ".conmgr":

[This file it does recognize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEfO8.png)

[This file it doesn't](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWsa2.png)

Comment: Do you want to recognize files with certain extensions as XML?

Comment: @MattSchuchard That's exactly what I would want, yes!